# how to get the value of data-ng-if/ng-if

Tags: angularjs

My html code is like that

```
<div data-ng-if="aaa.bbb.ccc == 0">         
            <input type="text"  name="ddd" id="eee"/>
</div>
```

May I ask, in my controller, is it possible to use something like (eee.ng-if==true)? I know in theory I can use ($scope.aaa.bbb.ccc==true), but the problem is that sometimes,$scope.aaa or $scope.aaa.bbb etc could be null so it causes error.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like

```
if($scope.aaa && $scope.aaa.bbb && $scope.aaa.bbb.ccc) {
   // Do something with $scope.aaa.bbb.ccc here
}
```

To answer your question: you can not get the value of an `ng-if`, the `ng-if` is a directive, which executes something like the above code.

Comment: Thank you very much. in fact i am using if($scope.aaa && $scope.aaa.bbb && $scope.aaa.bbb.ccc), it's not convenient. i just would like to confirm if there is something like eee.ng-if==true. Thank you again